# HTML canvas to video file

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

So I have the following code below. I am using Konva.js and Vue.js javascript frameworks to create a canvas editor.

It all works fine and good however I am trying to convert my canvas to a video file format. Currently I am able to make an object url but I would like to create an actual video file, that the user can download.

In short I want a video file at 30 fps. I have seen multiple libraries that attempt to do this but I don't know which one is the best one for my use case. I realize this is a lot of code but I wanted to give you the context. Where things start to get interesting is in the render function that calls startRecording.

```html
<template>
<div>
    <button @click="render">Render</button>
    <h2>Backgrounds</h2>
    <template v-for="background in backgrounds">
      <img
        :src="background.poster"
        class="backgrounds"
        @click="changeBackground(background.video)"
      />
    </template>
    <h2>Images</h2>
    <template v-for="image in images">
      <img :src="image.source" @click="addImage(image.source)" class="images" />
    </template>
    <br />
    <button @click="addText">Add Text</button>
    <button v-if="selectedNode" @click="removeNode">
      Remove selected {{ selectedNode.type }}
    </button>
    <label>Font:</label>
    <select v-model="selectedFont">
      <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
      <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
      <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
      <option value="Desoto">Desoto</option>
      <option value="Kalam">Kalam</option>
    </select>
    <label>Font Size</label>
    <input type="number" v-model="selectedFontSize" />
    <label>Font Style:</label>
    <select v-model="selectedFontStyle">
      <option value="normal">Normal</option>
      <option value="bold">Bold</option>
      <option value="italic">Italic</option>
    </select>
    <label>Color:</label>
    <input type="color" v-model="selectedColor" />
    <button
      v-if="selectedNode && selectedNode.type === 'text'"
      @click="updateText"
    >
      Update Text
    </button>
    <br />
    <video
      v-if="test"
      :src="test"
      :width="width / 2"
      :height="height / 2"
      controls
    />
    <a v-if="file" :href="file" download>download</a>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      source: null,
      stage: null,
      layer: null,
      video: null,
      captures: [],
      backgrounds: [
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/3oref310k1uud86w/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/3oref310k1uud86w/main/720/3oref310k1uud86w_720.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww/main/720/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww_720.mp4"
        }
      ],
      images: [
        {
          source:
            "https://www.sideshow.com/storage/product-images/903656/yoda_star-wars_square.jpg"
        },
        {
          source:
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/bf/Darth_Maul.png/220px-Darth_Maul.png"
        }
      ],
      backgroundVideo: null,
      imageGroups: [],
      anim: null,
      selectedNode: null,
      selectedFont: "Arial",
      selectedColor: "black",
      selectedFontSize: 20,
      selectedFontStyle: "normal",
      width: 1280,
      height: 720,
      texts: [],
      test: null,
      file: null,
      interval: null
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.initCanvas();
  },
  methods: {
    changeBackground(source) {
      this.source = source;
      this.video.src = this.source;
      this.anim.stop();
      this.anim.start();
      this.video.play();
    },
    removeNode() {
      if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "text") {
        this.selectedNode.transformer.destroy(
          this.selectedNode.text.transformer
        );
        this.selectedNode.text.destroy(this.selectedNode.text);
        this.texts.splice(this.selectedNode.text.index - 1, 1);
        this.selectedNode = null;
        this.layer.draw();
      } else if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type == "image") {
        this.selectedNode.group.destroy(this.selectedNode);
        this.imageGroups.splice(this.selectedNode.group.index - 1, 1);
        this.selectedNode = null;
        this.layer.draw();
      }
    },
    async addImage(src) {
      const vm = this;
      let loaded = false;
      const imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.src = src;
      function process(img) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          img.onload = () => resolve(true);
        });
      }
      await process(imageObj);
      const image = new Konva.Image({
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        image: imageObj,
        position: (0, 0),
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        strokeWidth: 10,
        stroke: "blue",
        strokeEnabled: false
      });
      const group = new Konva.Group({
        draggable: true
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      addAnchor(group, 0, 0, "topLeft");
      addAnchor(group, 200, 0, "topRight");
      addAnchor(group, 200, 200, "bottomRight");
      addAnchor(group, 0, 200, "bottomLeft");
      image.on("click", function() {
        vm.hideAllHelpers();
        vm.selectedNode = { type: "image", group };
        group.find("Circle").show();

        vm.layer.draw();
      });
      image.on("mouseover", function(evt) {
        if (vm.selectedNode && vm.selectedNode.type === "image") {
          const index = image.getParent().index;
          const groupId = vm.selectedNode.group.index;
          if (index != groupId) {
            evt.target.strokeEnabled(true);
            vm.layer.draw();
          }
        } else {
          evt.target.strokeEnabled(true);
          vm.layer.draw();
        }
      });
      image.on("mouseout", function(evt) {
        evt.target.strokeEnabled(false);
        vm.layer.draw();
      });
      vm.hideAllHelpers();
      group.find("Circle").show();
      group.add(image);
      vm.layer.add(group);
      vm.imageGroups.push(group);

      vm.selectedNode = { type: "image", group };
      vm.layer.draw();

      function update(activeAnchor) {
        const group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        let topLeft = group.get(".topLeft")[0];
        let topRight = group.get(".topRight")[0];
        let bottomRight = group.get(".bottomRight")[0];
        let bottomLeft = group.get(".bottomLeft")[0];
        let image = group.get("Image")[0];

        let anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        let anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
          case "topLeft":
            topRight.y(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "topRight":
            topLeft.y(anchorY);
            bottomRight.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "bottomRight":
            bottomLeft.y(anchorY);
            topRight.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "bottomLeft":
            bottomRight.y(anchorY);
            topLeft.x(anchorX);
            break;
        }

        image.position(topLeft.position());

        let width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        let height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if (width && height) {
          image.width(width);
          image.height(height);
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        let stage = vm.stage;
        let layer = vm.layer;

        let anchor = new Konva.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: "#666",
          fill: "#ddd",
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on("dragmove", function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
          group.draggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on("dragend", function() {
          group.draggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
          let layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
          this.strokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mouseout", function() {
          let layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          this.strokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
    },
    hideAllHelpers() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.texts.length; i++) {
        this.texts[i].transformer.hide();
      }
      for (let b = 0; b < this.imageGroups.length; b++) {
        this.imageGroups[b].find("Circle").hide();
      }
    },
    startRecording(canvas, duration) {
      const chunks = []; // here we will store our recorded media chunks (Blobs)
      const stream = canvas.captureStream(); // grab our canvas MediaStream
      const rec = new MediaRecorder(stream); // init the recorder
      // every time the recorder has new data, we will store it in our array
      rec.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
      // only when the recorder stops, we construct a complete Blob from all the chunks
      rec.onstop = async e => {
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
          type: "video/webm"
        });
        const reader = new FileReader();
        this.test = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onload = e => {
          this.file = e.target.result;
        };
      };
      rec.start();
      setTimeout(() => rec.stop(), duration);
    },
    async render() {
      this.test = null;
      this.file = null;
      this.hideAllHelpers();
      this.selectedNode = null;
      this.video.currentTime = 0;
      this.video.loop = false;
      const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      const duration = this.video.duration * 1000;
      this.startRecording(canvas, duration);
      // this.interval = setInterval(async () => {
      //   await this.video.pause();
      //   this.captures.push(await this.stage.toDataURL());
      //   console.log(this.captures.length);
      //   await this.video.play();
      // }, 1000 / 30);
      this.layer.draw();
    },
    updateText() {
      if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "text") {
        const text = this.selectedNode.text;
        const transformer = this.selectedNode.transformer;
        text.fontSize(this.selectedFontSize);
        text.fontFamily(this.selectedFont);
        text.fontStyle(this.selectedFontStyle);
        text.fill(this.selectedColor);
        this.layer.draw();
      }
    },
    addText() {
      const vm = this;
      const text = new Konva.Text({
        text: "new text " + (vm.texts.length + 1),
        x: 50,
        y: 80,
        fontSize: this.selectedFontSize,
        fontFamily: this.selectedFont,
        fontStyle: this.selectedFontStyle,
        fill: this.selectedColor,
        align: "center",
        width: this.width * 0.5,
        draggable: true
      });
      const transformer = new Konva.Transformer({
        node: text,
        keepRatio: true,
        enabledAnchors: ["top-left", "top-right", "bottom-left", "bottom-right"]
      });
      text.on("click", async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.texts.length; i++) {
          let item = this.texts[i];
          if (item.index === text.index) {
            let transformer = item.transformer;
            this.selectedNode = { type: "text", text, transformer };
            this.selectedFontSize = text.fontSize();
            this.selectedFont = text.fontFamily();
            this.selectedFontStyle = text.fontStyle();
            this.selectedColor = text.fill();
            vm.hideAllHelpers();
            transformer.show();
            transformer.moveToTop();
            text.moveToTop();
            vm.layer.draw();
            break;
          }
        }
      });
      text.on("mouseover", () => {
        transformer.show();
        this.layer.draw();
      });
      text.on("mouseout", () => {
        if (
          (this.selectedNode &&
            this.selectedNode.text &&
            this.selectedNode.text.index != text.index) ||
          (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "image") ||
          !this.selectedNode
        ) {
          transformer.hide();
          this.layer.draw();
        }
      });
      text.on("dblclick", () => {
        text.hide();
        transformer.hide();
        vm.layer.draw();
        let textPosition = text.absolutePosition();

        let stageBox = vm.stage.container().getBoundingClientRect();

        let areaPosition = {
          x: stageBox.left + textPosition.x,
          y: stageBox.top + textPosition.y
        };

        let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        window.document.body.appendChild(textarea);
        textarea.value = text.text();
        textarea.style.position = "absolute";
        textarea.style.top = areaPosition.y + "px";
        textarea.style.left = areaPosition.x + "px";
        textarea.style.width = text.width() - text.padding() * 2 + "px";
        textarea.style.height = text.height() - text.padding() * 2 + 5 + "px";
        textarea.style.fontSize = text.fontSize() + "px";
        textarea.style.border = "none";
        textarea.style.padding = "0px";
        textarea.style.margin = "0px";
        textarea.style.overflow = "hidden";
        textarea.style.background = "none";
        textarea.style.outline = "none";
        textarea.style.resize = "none";
        textarea.style.lineHeight = text.lineHeight();
        textarea.style.fontFamily = text.fontFamily();
        textarea.style.transformOrigin = "left top";
        textarea.style.textAlign = text.align();
        textarea.style.color = text.fill();
        let rotation = text.rotation();
        let transform = "";
        if (rotation) {
          transform += "rotateZ(" + rotation + "deg)";
        }
        let px = 0;
        let isFirefox =
          navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1;
        if (isFirefox) {
          px += 2 + Math.round(text.fontSize() / 20);
        }
        transform += "translateY(-" + px + "px)";
        textarea.style.transform = transform;
        textarea.style.height = "auto";
        textarea.focus();

        // start
        function removeTextarea() {
          textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);
          window.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
          text.show();
          transformer.show();
          transformer.forceUpdate();
          vm.layer.draw();
        }

        function setTextareaWidth(newWidth) {
          if (!newWidth) {
            // set width for placeholder
            newWidth = text.placeholder.length * text.fontSize();
          }
          // some extra fixes on different browsers
          let isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(
            navigator.userAgent
          );
          let isFirefox =
            navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1;
          if (isSafari || isFirefox) {
            newWidth = Math.ceil(newWidth);
          }

          let isEdge =
            document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent);
          if (isEdge) {
            newWidth += 1;
          }
          textarea.style.width = newWidth + "px";
        }

        textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          // hide on enter
          // but don't hide on shift + enter
          if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            text.text(textarea.value);
            removeTextarea();
          }
          // on esc do not set value back to node
          if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            removeTextarea();
          }
        });

        textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          let scale = text.getAbsoluteScale().x;
          setTextareaWidth(text.width() * scale);
          textarea.style.height = "auto";
          textarea.style.height =
            textarea.scrollHeight + text.fontSize() + "px";
        });

        function handleOutsideClick(e) {
          if (e.target !== textarea) {
            text.text(textarea.value);
            removeTextarea();
          }
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
        });
        // end
      });
      text.transformer = transformer;
      this.texts.push(text);
      this.layer.add(text);
      this.layer.add(transformer);
      this.hideAllHelpers();
      this.selectedNode = { type: "text", text, transformer };
      transformer.show();
      this.layer.draw();
    },
    initCanvas() {
      const vm = this;
      this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: vm.width,
        height: vm.height
      });
      this.layer = new Konva.Layer();

      this.stage.add(this.layer);

      let video = document.createElement("video");
      video.setAttribute("id", "video");
      video.setAttribute("ref", "video");
      if (this.source) {
        video.src = this.source;
      }
      video.preload = "auto";
      video.loop = "loop";
      video.style.display = "none";
      this.video = video;
      this.backgroundVideo = new Konva.Image({
        image: vm.video,
        draggable: false
      });
      this.video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e) {
        vm.backgroundVideo.width(vm.width);
        vm.backgroundVideo.height(vm.height);
      });
      this.video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
        console.log("the video ended");
        vm.anim.stop();
        vm.video.currentTime = 0;
        vm.video.loop = "loop";
        vm.anim.start();
        vm.video.play();
      });

      this.anim = new Konva.Animation(function() {
        console.log("animation called");
        // do nothing, animation just need to update the layer
      }, vm.layer);

      this.layer.add(this.backgroundVideo);
      this.layer.draw();
      const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      canvas.style.border = "3px solid red";
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
/* #test {
  width: 432px !important;
  height: 432px !important;
} */
.backgrounds,
.images {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Does your approach work?

Comment: My question is how do I capture an image sequence of the canvas at 30 frames a second?

Comment: I think the simplest solution is just generate frames (images) with canvas export. And then generate a video from frames with a library (probably on the backend side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

captured a sequence and made it a webm file using whammy.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="render">Render</button>
    <h2>Backgrounds</h2>
    <template v-for="background in backgrounds">
      <img
        :src="background.poster"
        class="backgrounds"
        @click="changeBackground(background.video)"
      />
    </template>
    <h2>Images</h2>
    <template v-for="image in images">
      <img :src="image.source" @click="addImage(image.source)" class="images" />
    </template>
    <br />
    <button @click="addText">Add Text</button>
    <button v-if="selectedNode" @click="removeNode">
      Remove selected {{ selectedNode.type }}
    </button>
    <label>Font:</label>
    <select v-model="selectedFont">
      <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
      <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
      <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
      <option value="Desoto">Desoto</option>
      <option value="Kalam">Kalam</option>
    </select>
    <label>Font Size</label>
    <input type="number" v-model="selectedFontSize" />
    <label>Font Style:</label>
    <select v-model="selectedFontStyle">
      <option value="normal">Normal</option>
      <option value="bold">Bold</option>
      <option value="italic">Italic</option>
    </select>
    <label>Color:</label>
    <input type="color" v-model="selectedColor" />
    <button
      v-if="selectedNode && selectedNode.type === 'text'"
      @click="updateText"
    >
      Update Text
    </button>
    <br />
    <video
      id="preview"
      v-show="preview"
      :src="preview"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
      preload="auto"
      controls
    />
    <a v-if="file" :href="file" download="video.webm">download</a>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      source: null,
      stage: null,
      layer: null,
      video: null,
      captures: [],
      backgrounds: [
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/3oref310k1uud86w/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/3oref310k1uud86w/main/1080/3oref310k1uud86w_1080.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww/main/1080/3yj2e30tk5x6x0ww_1080.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/2ez931ik1mggd6j/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/2ez931ik1mggd6j/main/1080/2ez931ik1mggd6j_1080.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster: "/api/files/stock/yxrt4ej4jvimyk15/poster/poster.jpg",
          video:
            "/api/files/stock/yxrt4ej4jvimyk15/main/1080/yxrt4ej4jvimyk15_1080.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster:
            "https://images.costco-static.com/ImageDelivery/imageService?profileId=12026540&itemId=100424771-847&recipeName=680",
          video: "/api/files/jedi/surfing.mp4"
        },
        {
          poster:
            "https://thedefensepost.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/us-soldiers-afghanistan-4308413-1170x610.jpg",
          video: "/api/files/jedi/soldiers.mp4"
        }
      ],
      images: [
        { source: "/api/files/jedi/solo.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/yoda.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/yodaChristmas.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/darthMaul.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/darthMaul1.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/trump.jpg" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/hat.png" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/trump.png" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/bernie.png" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/skywalker.png" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/vader.gif" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/vader2.gif" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/yoda.gif" },
        { source: "api/files/jedi/kylo.gif" }
      ],
      backgroundVideo: null,
      imageGroups: [],
      anim: null,
      selectedNode: null,
      selectedFont: "Arial",
      selectedColor: "black",
      selectedFontSize: 20,
      selectedFontStyle: "normal",
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      texts: [],
      preview: null,
      file: null,
      canvas: null
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.initCanvas();
  },
  methods: {
    changeBackground(source) {
      this.source = source;
      this.video.src = this.source;
      this.anim.stop();
      this.anim.start();
      this.video.play();
    },
    removeNode() {
      if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "text") {
        this.selectedNode.transformer.destroy(
          this.selectedNode.text.transformer
        );
        this.selectedNode.text.destroy(this.selectedNode.text);
        this.texts.splice(this.selectedNode.text.index - 1, 1);
        this.selectedNode = null;
        this.layer.draw();
      } else if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type == "image") {
        this.selectedNode.group.destroy(this.selectedNode);
        this.imageGroups.splice(this.selectedNode.group.index - 1, 1);
        this.selectedNode = null;
        this.layer.draw();
      }
    },
    async addImage(src) {
      let imageObj = null;
      const type = src.slice(src.lastIndexOf("."));
      const vm = this;
      function process(img) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          img.onload = () => resolve({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
        });
      }
      imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.src = src;
      imageObj.width = 200;
      imageObj.height = 200;
      await process(imageObj);

      if (type === ".gif") {
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("id", "gif");
        async function onDrawFrame(ctx, frame) {
          ctx.drawImage(frame.buffer, frame.x, frame.y);
          // redraw the layer
          vm.layer.draw();
        }
        gifler(src).frames(canvas, onDrawFrame);

        canvas.onload = async () => {
          canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
        };
        imageObj = canvas;
        const gif = new Image();
        gif.src = src;
        const gifImage = await process(gif);
        imageObj.width = gifImage.width;
        imageObj.height = gifImage.height;
      }
      const image = new Konva.Image({
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        image: imageObj,
        width: imageObj.width,
        height: imageObj.height,
        position: (0, 0),
        strokeWidth: 10,
        stroke: "blue",
        strokeEnabled: false
      });

      this.frame = null;
      const group = new Konva.Group({
        draggable: true
      });
      // add the shape to the layer
      addAnchor(group, 0, 0, "topLeft");
      addAnchor(group, imageObj.width, 0, "topRight");
      addAnchor(group, imageObj.width, imageObj.height, "bottomRight");
      addAnchor(group, 0, imageObj.height, "bottomLeft");
      imageObj = null;
      image.on("click", function() {
        vm.hideAllHelpers();
        vm.selectedNode = { type: "image", group };
        group.find("Circle").show();

        vm.layer.draw();
      });
      image.on("mouseover", function(evt) {
        if (vm.selectedNode && vm.selectedNode.type === "image") {
          const index = image.getParent().index;
          const groupId = vm.selectedNode.group.index;
          if (index != groupId) {
            evt.target.strokeEnabled(true);
            vm.layer.draw();
          }
        } else {
          evt.target.strokeEnabled(true);
          vm.layer.draw();
        }
      });
      image.on("mouseout", function(evt) {
        evt.target.strokeEnabled(false);
        vm.layer.draw();
      });
      vm.hideAllHelpers();
      group.find("Circle").show();
      group.add(image);
      vm.layer.add(group);
      vm.imageGroups.push(group);

      vm.selectedNode = { type: "image", group };
      vm.layer.draw();

      function update(activeAnchor) {
        const group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        let topLeft = group.get(".topLeft")[0];
        let topRight = group.get(".topRight")[0];
        let bottomRight = group.get(".bottomRight")[0];
        let bottomLeft = group.get(".bottomLeft")[0];
        let image = group.get("Image")[0];

        let anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        let anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
          case "topLeft":
            topRight.y(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "topRight":
            topLeft.y(anchorY);
            bottomRight.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "bottomRight":
            bottomLeft.y(anchorY);
            topRight.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case "bottomLeft":
            bottomRight.y(anchorY);
            topLeft.x(anchorX);
            break;
        }

        image.position(topLeft.position());

        let width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        let height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if (width && height) {
          image.width(width);
          image.height(height);
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        let stage = vm.stage;
        let layer = vm.layer;

        let anchor = new Konva.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: "#666",
          fill: "#ddd",
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on("dragmove", function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
          group.draggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on("dragend", function() {
          group.draggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
          let layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
          this.strokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on("mouseout", function() {
          let layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          this.strokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
    },
    hideAllHelpers() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.texts.length; i++) {
        this.texts[i].transformer.hide();
      }
      for (let b = 0; b < this.imageGroups.length; b++) {
        this.imageGroups[b].find("Circle").hide();
      }
    },
    async startRecording(duration) {
      const chunks = []; // here we will store our recorded media chunks (Blobs)
      const stream = this.canvas.captureStream(30); // grab our canvas MediaStream
      const rec = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        videoBitsPerSecond: 20000 * 1000
      });
      // every time the recorder has new data, we will store it in our array
      rec.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
      // // only when the recorder stops, we construct a complete Blob from all the chunks
      rec.onstop = async e => {
        this.anim.stop();

        const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
          type: "video/webm"
        });

        this.preview = await URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const video = window.document.getElementById("preview");
        const previewVideo = new Konva.Image({
          image: video,
          draggable: false,
          width: this.width,
          height: this.height
        });
        this.layer.add(previewVideo);

        console.log("video", video);
        video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
          console.log("preview ended");
          if (!this.file) {
            const vid = new Whammy.fromImageArray(this.captures, 30);
            this.file = URL.createObjectURL(vid);
          }
          previewVideo.destroy();
          this.anim.stop();
          this.anim.start();
          this.video.play();
        });
        let seekResolve;

        video.addEventListener("seeked", async () => {
          if (seekResolve) seekResolve();
        });
        video.addEventListener("loadeddata", async () => {
          let interval = 1 / 30;
          let currentTime = 0;
          while (currentTime <= duration && !this.file) {
            video.currentTime = currentTime;
            await new Promise(r => (seekResolve = r));

            this.layer.draw();
            let base64ImageData = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/webp");
            this.captures.push(base64ImageData);
            currentTime += interval;
            video.currentTime = currentTime;
          }

          this.layer.draw();
        });
      };
      rec.start();
      setTimeout(() => rec.stop(), duration);
    },
    async render() {
      this.captures = [];
      this.preview = null;
      this.file = null;
      console.log(this.captures.length);
      this.hideAllHelpers();
      this.selectedNode = null;
      this.video.currentTime = 0;
      this.video.loop = false;
      const duration = this.video.duration * 1000;
      this.startRecording(duration);
      this.layer.draw();
    },
    updateText() {
      if (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "text") {
        const text = this.selectedNode.text;
        const transformer = this.selectedNode.transformer;
        text.fontSize(this.selectedFontSize);
        text.fontFamily(this.selectedFont);
        text.fontStyle(this.selectedFontStyle);
        text.fill(this.selectedColor);
        this.layer.draw();
      }
    },
    addText() {
      const vm = this;
      const text = new Konva.Text({
        text: "new text " + (vm.texts.length + 1),
        x: 50,
        y: 80,
        fontSize: this.selectedFontSize,
        fontFamily: this.selectedFont,
        fontStyle: this.selectedFontStyle,
        fill: this.selectedColor,
        align: "center",
        width: this.width * 0.5,
        draggable: true
      });
      const transformer = new Konva.Transformer({
        node: text,
        keepRatio: true,
        enabledAnchors: ["top-left", "top-right", "bottom-left", "bottom-right"]
      });
      text.on("click", async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.texts.length; i++) {
          let item = this.texts[i];
          if (item.index === text.index) {
            let transformer = item.transformer;
            this.selectedNode = { type: "text", text, transformer };
            this.selectedFontSize = text.fontSize();
            this.selectedFont = text.fontFamily();
            this.selectedFontStyle = text.fontStyle();
            this.selectedColor = text.fill();
            vm.hideAllHelpers();
            transformer.show();
            transformer.moveToTop();
            text.moveToTop();
            vm.layer.draw();
            break;
          }
        }
      });
      text.on("mouseover", () => {
        transformer.show();
        this.layer.draw();
      });
      text.on("mouseout", () => {
        if (
          (this.selectedNode &&
            this.selectedNode.text &&
            this.selectedNode.text.index != text.index) ||
          (this.selectedNode && this.selectedNode.type === "image") ||
          !this.selectedNode
        ) {
          transformer.hide();
          this.layer.draw();
        }
      });
      text.on("dblclick", () => {
        text.hide();
        transformer.hide();
        vm.layer.draw();
        let textPosition = text.absolutePosition();

        let stageBox = vm.stage.container().getBoundingClientRect();

        let areaPosition = {
          x: stageBox.left + textPosition.x,
          y: stageBox.top + textPosition.y
        };

        let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        window.document.body.appendChild(textarea);
        textarea.value = text.text();
        textarea.style.position = "absolute";
        textarea.style.top = areaPosition.y + "px";
        textarea.style.left = areaPosition.x + "px";
        textarea.style.width = text.width() - text.padding() * 2 + "px";
        textarea.style.height = text.height() - text.padding() * 2 + 5 + "px";
        textarea.style.fontSize = text.fontSize() + "px";
        textarea.style.border = "none";
        textarea.style.padding = "0px";
        textarea.style.margin = "0px";
        textarea.style.overflow = "hidden";
        textarea.style.background = "none";
        textarea.style.outline = "none";
        textarea.style.resize = "none";
        textarea.style.lineHeight = text.lineHeight();
        textarea.style.fontFamily = text.fontFamily();
        textarea.style.transformOrigin = "left top";
        textarea.style.textAlign = text.align();
        textarea.style.color = text.fill();
        let rotation = text.rotation();
        let transform = "";
        if (rotation) {
          transform += "rotateZ(" + rotation + "deg)";
        }
        let px = 0;
        let isFirefox =
          navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1;
        if (isFirefox) {
          px += 2 + Math.round(text.fontSize() / 20);
        }
        transform += "translateY(-" + px + "px)";
        textarea.style.transform = transform;
        textarea.style.height = "auto";
        textarea.focus();

        // start
        function removeTextarea() {
          textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);
          window.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
          text.show();
          transformer.show();
          transformer.forceUpdate();
          vm.layer.draw();
        }

        function setTextareaWidth(newWidth) {
          if (!newWidth) {
            // set width for placeholder
            newWidth = text.placeholder.length * text.fontSize();
          }
          // some extra fixes on different browsers
          let isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(
            navigator.userAgent
          );
          let isFirefox =
            navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1;
          if (isSafari || isFirefox) {
            newWidth = Math.ceil(newWidth);
          }

          let isEdge =
            document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent);
          if (isEdge) {
            newWidth += 1;
          }
          textarea.style.width = newWidth + "px";
        }

        textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          // hide on enter
          // but don't hide on shift + enter
          if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            text.text(textarea.value);
            removeTextarea();
          }
          // on esc do not set value back to node
          if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            removeTextarea();
          }
        });

        textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          let scale = text.getAbsoluteScale().x;
          setTextareaWidth(text.width() * scale);
          textarea.style.height = "auto";
          textarea.style.height =
            textarea.scrollHeight + text.fontSize() + "px";
        });

        function handleOutsideClick(e) {
          if (e.target !== textarea) {
            text.text(textarea.value);
            removeTextarea();
          }
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
        });
        // end
      });
      text.transformer = transformer;
      this.texts.push(text);
      this.layer.add(text);
      this.layer.add(transformer);
      this.hideAllHelpers();
      this.selectedNode = { type: "text", text, transformer };
      transformer.show();
      this.layer.draw();
    },
    initCanvas() {
      const vm = this;
      this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: vm.width,
        height: vm.height
      });
      this.layer = new Konva.Layer();

      this.stage.add(this.layer);

      let video = document.createElement("video");
      video.setAttribute("id", "video");
      video.setAttribute("ref", "video");
      if (this.source) {
        video.src = this.source;
      }
      video.preload = "auto";
      video.loop = "loop";
      video.style.display = "none";
      this.video = video;
      this.backgroundVideo = new Konva.Image({
        image: vm.video,
        draggable: false
      });
      this.video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e) {
        vm.backgroundVideo.width(vm.width);
        vm.backgroundVideo.height(vm.height);
      });
      this.video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
        console.log("the video ended");
        this.anim.stop();
        this.anim.start();
        this.video.loop = "loop";
        this.video.play();
      });

      this.anim = new Konva.Animation(function() {
        console.log("animation called");
        // do nothing, animation just need to update the layer
      }, vm.layer);

      this.layer.add(this.backgroundVideo);
      this.layer.draw();
      const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      canvas.style.border = "3px solid red";
      this.canvas = canvas;
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.backgrounds,
.images {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
</style>
```